# rsync restore from backup

Tags: linux, rsync

I am using command sudo `sudo rsync -axvq / user@ip:/mnt` to backup original disk.

Now original hdd failed so I have new hdd to replace old original hdd. But backups are in remote disk under /mnt
Now I take backup hdd, connect it via usb to the machine with linux, and I also connect blank new hdd via second usb to this linux machine. What exact command should I run locally on linux box to restore my backups to new hdd please? Is it the same `sudo rsync -axvq /mnt/sdbackup/mnt /mnt/sdnew/` ??

many thanks

Comment: Have you recreated the original disk's partition table on the new disk? What command did you use to test your backups? Not using `-H` in the backup means that hard links are not preserved - is this intended? Does [this](https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-backup-linux-system-rsync) procedure help?

Comment: disk's partition - no, it is one new whole partition (new hdd from shop). No test command honestly. Not usin -H - no idea what this means. sorry, I am not linux sophisticated user :(

Comment: So no separate `/home` or swap. System is not set up with LVM. `-H` is a standard `rsync` switch that should have been used. You relied on a backup but never tested to see if you could restore from backup. My recommendation  is to install a new system from scratch and then see if you can get any data back. Data is usually deemed as unimportant if its not backed up and the backup verified.